# Excel VBA: Input Box to AutoFill Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following on a CommandButton(2). It is 2 of 6 CommandButtons using the same code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim myValue As String
Dim lastCel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J1")
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton2")
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.RowHeight
    Set lastCel = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    myValue = InputBox("Enter Advice No", "Check No")
    Range("J2:J" & lastCel.Row).Formula = "=IF($A2<>""""," & """" & myValue & """" & ","""")"
    Range("J2:J" & lastCel.Row).Value = Range("J2:J" & lastCel.Row).Value
    Range("J2").Value = myValue
End With  
End Sub
```

The code is tied to a command button which prompts the user for input information and then is supposed to autofill the column with the entered value so long as their is a value in Column A. Unlike the other 5 CommandButtons this one will not work.

When I enter any value it will return the entered value for cell J2.

It then returns, =IF($A2<>"","00682300",""), for each cell thereafter.

The most common entry is a number in the listed format. I am not sure why it is working for every other CommandButton except this one.

Comment: How doesn't it work? If you input `asd` it still takes what's already in `J2` and uses that for `myValue`? If you step through with `F8`, after the `myValue = ` line, does it correctly set `myValue`? (Hover the mouse over that variable, or add `Debug.Print myValue` in there to make sure it's at least assigning the variable correctly.

Comment: What is it doing that you don't want it to?  It is putting the formula in every cell in J, and then setting the value = to the value in the cells in J, then it's setting J2 to be the value that was input with the Inputbox.

Comment: This is my confusion that it doesn't work.

It works for every other column with no problem. It correctly sets myValue and it returns the, =IF($A2<>"","00682300",""), on every line instead of just 00682300 or any other value entered. So it is reading the values in Column A correctly it is just not outputting the entered value in Column J. It is obviously reading the input value correctly but for cells J3:J it is just returning the =IF($A2<>"","00682300","")

Comment: J
    J1 - CommandButton
    J2 - asd
    J3 - =IF($A2<>"","asd","")
    J4 - =IF($A2<>"","asd","")
    J5 - =IF($A2<>"","asd","")

so on and so on

Comment: Ok so I figured it out after beating my head in. It was an error in another line of code that made the Column Text instead on General. Changing that seems to have fixed it and the code works fine